# Not being able to create entity manager factory using jpa in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am using jpa , hibernate and eclipse to build a spring mvc application. Following is my controller:

```
package com.something.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.drc.model.Project;
import com.drc.service.ProjectService;

@RestController("projectController")
@RequestMapping("/project")
public class ProjectController {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectService projectService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{projectName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createProject (@PathVariable String projectName)
    {

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("punit");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();       
        TypedQuery<Project> query= em.createQuery("from project where name=:projectName",Project.class);
        List<Project> results= query.getResultList();

         if(results.size()>0)
         {
             return "there are entries";

         }

         else
         {
             return "there are no entries";
         }


    }
```

This is my jpaContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.drc" />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.drc.repository"/>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"></entry>
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
                <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apecadprojects?autoReconnect=true" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

</beans>



Whenever i browse to the page say localhost:8080/projectname/project/myname i get the following error
```

[image]

As you can see it is not allowing me to create an EntityManagerFactory..Why???

Following is my persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="punit">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

What am i doing wrong??

Update Ok now after trying for some hours now i get the following error can please somebody point out what is the problem?? is my hql wrong??

[image]

Comment: guys my hql query was wrong.......that's why i got the syntax exception error........figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the persistence.xml is in the META-INF directory in the classpath.

Comment: Well, the first I would do is decouple the REST controller with your presistency to make as fewer variables possible that might get in the way (it's better design, more modular, easier to test etc.. )
It doesn't make too much sense creating your EntityManager more than once anyway (especially not on every client request).

Comment: This is just the test code.......I am not planning to create it every time the client requests it........

Comment: Maybe the provider is missing ? Does org.hibernate.jpa.PersistenceProvider exists in the classpath ?

Comment: Shaprio........I am a newbie in spring...Do you mean it should be inside my maven dependancies inside hibernate-entity manager jar??

Comment: If you want to use Hibernate as your JPA provider you must have the needed jars in your pom.xml.


In addition, if you're integrating Spring and JPA I don't believe you need to create the EntityManager yourself but rather use @PersistenceContext and have Spring inject it to your classes.

There are lots of guides for doing this, check out this one : 
http://www.objectdb.com/tutorial/jpa/eclipse/spring

Comment: there is org.hibernate.jpa inside hibernate-core jar but it has got a white symbol in front not like other who have yellow in front of them......This means that it has to be imported right??

Comment: Sorry for the trouble but i needed to add the following line to persistence.xml

 <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

and it worked......

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not added  classname  in your persistence xml.

Add this in your persistence xml

```
<class>yourpackage.Project</class>
```

And in your enitity manager bean add the proeprty

```
<property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
```

Comment: after adding first line it says Class "package.projectname" cannot be resolved

Comment: Make sure you are giving the entire package name.. com.drc.model.Project

Comment: The class should be added inside <persistence-unit>

Comment: nope didn't work still getting the same error ........class "" cannot be resolved

Comment: Sorry for the trouble but i needed to add the following line to persistence.xml

 <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

and it worked......
Anyways thanks for help Nikhil